# Efficiently enumerate all subsets of an ordered set

Tags: combinatorics

What's the most efficient way to enumerate all (ordered) subsets of an ordered set? So, for example, given the ordered set $\{2, 5, 6\}$ (using the normal ordering for integers), I need the following:
$$\{\}, \{2\}, \{5\}, \{6\}, \{2, 5\}, \{2, 6\}, \{5, 6\}, \{2, 5, 6\}.$$
Smaller subsets should come first, but the ordering of the subsets of equal size is not important.

I'm looking for an algorithm that is efficient both in theory and in implementation (in a general purpose programming language) for very large sets.

Comment: Why are you interested in very large sets? The complexity of the algorithm is exponential anyway, it won't be possible to see any subsets of size greater than, say, 64 in our lifetime.

Comment: Search for "powerset" on [this page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html). $\;$

Answer (score 6):

One possibility is to generate separately all subsets of size $k$ using the following recursive approach:

> A $k$-subset of $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ is either a $k$-subset of $a_2,\ldots,a_n$ or $a_1$ adjoined to a $(k-1)$-subset of $a_2,\ldots,a_n$.

Run this recursive algorithm for $k=0,\ldots,n$. If you're careful, you will get a lexicographically ordered output.

Comment: That's nice for lexicographical order, but it seems OP is interested in [shortlex order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortlex_order) instead.

Comment: @Khaur Shortlex *is* lexicographic order for each of the sublists. My approach (as stated) *cannot* produce lexicographic order, since it is ordered by size.

Comment: Right, my initial reading was wrong, I got fooled by your mention of the lexicographical order at the end. The call graph seems rather nasty for iterating on $k$ though, maybe I'm still missing something.

Comment: @Khaur In python this algorithm takes just a few lines. (Python also supplies a library function for this.) Iterating on $k$ is the easiest part.

Comment: What I mean is that either you call the whole dependency graph (not recommendable for large sets) or you use some form of DP. If you iterate on $k$, you have to store the $k$-subsets for all of the $a_i,...,a_n$ until the next iteration, which will be largely redundant. If you instead iterate (backwards) on $i$, you get to store the subsets for all $k$, which are distinct by definition. However that also means you can no longer simply concatenate to keep the shortlex order from one iteration to the next, but with the right data structure it shouldn't be too much of a problem.

Comment: Oh nevermind I just realised that since the merging operation is as simple as concatenation you can store the $k$-subsets for $a_i,...,a_n$ as increments from $a_{i+1},...,a_n$

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in subsets of increasing size, then go for k = 1..n, enumerate all subsets of size k. This is a well-known problem with many possible solutions, one of which is described in wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system (see "Applications").