# Generating permutations with a given bubblesort distance

Tags: algorithms, permutations

I'm looking for an algorithm to randomly generate permutations on 1:n, which though have a defined [bubblesort distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance) d from 1:n, e.g. (2,3,1) and (3,1,2) are distance 1 from (1,2,3), (2,3,1) and (3,1,2) are d=2, finally (3,2,1) is d=3.

Naive approach is to flip a random sorted pair d times, however it seems it does not produce an uniform sample... The exact approach (generate all permutations at a given d and then sample) does not scale too well.

Comment: Can you count the number of permutations at a given distance? If so, you can try the approach in [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/107155/683). While the question is about unranking (given an index $i$, output the $i$'th object in some collection), you can easily convert it to a random generation algorithm by choosing the index uniformly at random.

Comment: Thanks; turns out the counts of permutation at each distance form the [Mahonian number triangle](https://oeis.org/A008302), which made me realise I'm looking to generate random permutation with a given number of inversions. And [GitHub has the code](https://github.com/ekhiru/random_perm_inversion). Time to understand what it does...